# formatting text with perl

Tags: perl

I have the a text on this template :

```
In 1935 he was asked to document the principal dancers and productions and 
George newly .

he continued to shoot fashion 
Bergdorf Goodman and Saks Fifth 
started a series of photographs .
```

and want to convert every paragraph to one line seprated by "\n" i.e the output will be:

```
In 1935 he was asked to document the principal dancers and productions George newly .

he continued to shoot fashion Bergdorf Goodman and Saks Fifth started a series of photographs .
```

how can i format such thing with perl could someone provide an example ?

I tried to use Text::Wrap like below but get unwanted results

```
$Text::Wrap::separator=' ';
my $text=fill("","",$text);
```

Comment: To achieve this with `Text::Wrap` you'll have to seperate the paragraphs first (`split "\n\n" , $text`) and then wrap each array element.

Comment: What is your intended usage? Just alter a text file? Fix a string/file handle within a script?

Comment: http://p3rl.org/Text::Autoformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-liner, you might try something like this:

```
perl -00 -l -pwe 's/\n//g' foo/george.txt
```

`-00` will set the input record separator `$/` to `""` and activate paragraph mode. `-l` will set output record separator `$\` to `"\n\n"` (in this case).

In script version:

```
$/ = ""; 
$\ = "\n\n";
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s/\n//g;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Text::Wrap but a) you need to read the file a paragraph at a time and b) you need to set an artificially high right margin.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Wrap;

$Text::Wrap::columns = 10_000;
local $/ = ''; # Always localise changes to $/

while (<DATA>) {
  print fill('', '', $_), "\n\n";
}

__DATA__
In 1935 he was asked to document the principal dancers and productions and 
George newly .

he continued to shoot fashion 
Bergdorf Goodman and Saks Fifth 
started a series of photographs .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/=""; #lines are paragraphs - perlfaq5
#files are command line args, or STDIN
while(<>){s/\n//g; print $_,"\n\n";}
```

Comment: tr/\n//d; is better than s///g here (because we are dealing with characters rather than patterns).

Comment: If you're setting `$/`, might as well set `$\ ` too.